# Как проверить в полноэкранном ли режиме окно в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

В программе, которую я пишу, нужна проверка на полноэкранный режим. Как осуществить это?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Я исправил, посмотри так хотел? isMaximized() возвращает True если окно на максимум, False если нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isMaximized() возвращает True если окно на максимум, False если

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #bdd3de;')
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.btn_test = QPushButton('Проверка окна')

        self.btn_test.clicked.connect(self.window_check)

        self.main_box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_box.addWidget(self.label)
        self.main_box.addWidget(self.btn_test)
        self.setLayout(self.main_box)

    def window_check(self):
        if self.isMaximized():
            self.label.setText('Окно на максимум')
        else:
            self.label.setText('Окно не максимум')




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло!